# As I can move a marker in a MapFragment in real time?

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

Please someone knows how to make a marker to move while a car is walking in a MapFragment android studio, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to update the location of the marker according to the car's position or you want to animate the marker. Check these

[move marker on google maps api 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312754/move-marker-on-google-maps-api-2)

[Move markers in google map v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is what I need